# Command system("cls") is not working only in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-c++, g++

So, I am starting with making projects in **c++** in **VSC** and I wanted my first project to be simple snake game.

I started setting up the frame and since you have a while loop that is making frame over and over, I have to clear my old frame. After looking on web i figured i could use command system("cls") with libraries stdlib.h and cstdlib each and both.When i ran the code it erased only one line of code.So after a few hours of searching for a solution i went to Code Blocks ran code and it ran the code correctly.I don't understand what setting is blocking this command to work..

Comment: `stdlib.h` and `cstdlib` would be the same thing, fyi.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ cursor library".  A snake game is not an easy project for a beginner.  Other games that don't involve animation are much simpler:  Hangman, FizzBuzz, Tic-Tac-Toe, Boggle, Nimb.  Card games are a little more difficult:  Uno, Mille-Bournes, War, BlackJack, Crazy Eights, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got it.When I was making borders for my game I set my width and height to be 40.Then I thought about it and remembered I saw someone saying that the command system("cls") clears only the full screen of terminal.If you put width and height to be 40 that's more than it fits in terminal so the terminal is never cleaned fully and that's why it didn't work properly..